# What does the middle dot in parentheses mean?

Tags: notation

The below picture is from section 3.3.1 in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.5401v2.pdf);

[image: Extract from paper]

I'm not familiar with the notation of using middle dots in square parenthesis. Are the authors using this simply to indicate that any two parameters can be passed to the function K?

Thank you,

Comment: @AlexG. A mod should promote this to an answer so this question can be closed off properly :P Thanks again!

Comment: There you go${}{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're correct. It's like using an underscore; it stands for an empty slot for parameters to be plugged into.